# Are resource bundle properties file supposed to be created manually

Tags: intellij-idea, internationalization, resourcebundle

I created a resource bundle file in the Intellij idea called login.properties with some key value pairs. Now I want to create a french version for it so I guess it should be named login_fr.properties 
But what about the text in french. The login.properties file has English text. Is there an automated way to create this login_fr.properties file? the file and the content bother tr